# how do I trigger the camera using motion detection?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, motion-detection

I am trying to trigger a camera using motion detection.

I have got a code which takes video and performs motion detection and capture and saves frames when the background changes. But the problem is that it takes multiple images of an object passing by. I only need to take one image, when the object is fully in the scene.

How do I trigger the camera only once when the object is in the middle and it is fully visible?

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure to exclude the noise so that you don't recognize stationary objects. The trees and power lines both look like they will constantly be recognized as objects passing the right if you don't filter them out. You could draw a mask that only includes the road and also use region labelling to exclude objects below a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

Try using tracker API in OpenCV, so if you detect car on the right like on te binary image, you can track it with tracker and ignore that region in analizing next frames.
in Python you can use `cv2.Tracker_create()` to create Tracker, next you apply Tracker on the object of intrests like your detected car.
[Tracker Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html)

Comment: I have a question for you, do you mean that should add tracker on top of my motion detection?

Comment: You can use tracker as tool for tracking elements that you earlier detect, so in next detections attempt you will ignore them. Add bounding box on new detected object and while tracker is following it change that box to black color what means it's nothing new detected. Correct me if I wrong understand your algo.